# recursive insert from table

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

What is the efficient way to do the following:

Let's say I have a table that looks like this (dbo.Student):

```
Date            StudentName   
10-01-2017         Alex K
10-01-2017         Mike J
11-01-2017         John W
12-01-2017         Marie A
12-01-2017         Steph V
```

I need to insert these records as snapshots. So, my final results would be:

```
  Cutoff            Date            StudentName   
   10-01-2017      10-01-2017         Alex K
   10-01-2017      10-01-2017         Mike J
   11-01-2017      10-01-2017         Alex K
   11-01-2017      10-01-2017         Mike J
   11-01-2017      11-01-2017         John W
   12-01-2017      10-01-2017         Alex K
   12-01-2017      10-01-2017         Mike J
   12-01-2017      11-01-2017         John W
   12-01-2017      12-01-2017         Marie A
   12-01-2017      12-01-2017         Steph V
```

So, for each period get a snapshot where Date<= cutoff date.

My current solution works as follows:

Create additional table dbo.Dates that looks like this:

```
Dates
10-01-2017
11-01-2017
12-01-2017
01-01-2018
...
```

Then loop through table Dates and run insert statement:

```
insert into myTable
select * from dbo.Student where Date<=CutoffDate
```

Issue: insert statement is executed sometimes more than 100 times. (My source table can have 100k-2million rows.) so running this logic in a loop is not ideal. And I can have up to 100-500 dates in dbo.Dates.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the separate table, you can do the insert in one step:

```
insert into mytable (cutoff, date, name)
    select t.date, t.date, t.name
    from mytable t join
         dates d
         on d.date >= t.date;
```

EDIT:

If the dates are in `mytable`, you can do:

```
insert into mytable (cutoff, date, name)
    select t.date, t.date, t.name
    from mytable t join
         (select distinct date from mytable) d
         on d.date >= t.date;
```

However, this assumes that the table has only the dates you are interested in.

Comment: This looks great. Thanks Gordon!

Comment: I do not have this dates table initially but I create temp table since I thought this might be faster. Do you know if it is possible to avoid creating temp table if I only have final date cutoff (eg. 12-01-2017)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (:

```
SELECT DateDtls.Date,YourTable.Date,YourTable.StudentName
FROM   YourTable
CROSS JOIN (SELECT   DISTINCT Date FROM   YourTable) AS DateDtls
WHERE YourTable.Date <= DateDtls.Date
```